# Show file names in git checkout -p

Tags: git

`git checkout -p BranchX` shows the different chunks using the `--patch` format:

Example:

```
@@ -733,7 +733,7 @@ LICENSE URL ... https://github.com/typeplate/bower/blob/master/license.txt
 }
 .c .Utility--text-red,
 .c .Utility--text-red a {
-  color: #9f251a !important;
+  color: #ca171e !important;
 }
 .c .Utility--text-gold,
 .c .Utility--text-gold a {
Apply this hunk to index and worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,K,j,J,g,e,?]?
```

How can I have this command show file paths (and names) also?

I've searched the docs for `git-checkout`and `git-add` but I haven't found anything.

Thanks

Comment: Which git version are you using? Using Git 1.9.4 the file paths are displayed above the file range line (`@@ ... @@ ...`).

Comment: Indeed I updated git and they show up. Not sure what to do with this question now.

Comment: I would add an answer to accept but I'm currently on mobile. I will do when I get home and look up on which version this was added.

Comment: Which version did you use before?

Comment: I used version 1.9.2

Comment: It seems to me that this was added long ago, and should have worked in 1.9.2. Due to this I'm obliged to conclude that this might have been a configuration issue or something similar. Not sure what to write in an answer now.